# Nuxt alias not found

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I've got a nuxt project in a 'mono-repo'. I want to use `components` in my nuxt project from a different project within the mono repo.

In `nuxt.config.ts` I've added an alias:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt/config";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss"],
  srcDir: "src",
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  imports: {
    autoImport: false,
  },
  typescript: {
    strict: true,
    typeCheck: "build",
  },
  alias: {
    "@components": "../components/src/components",
  },
});
```

It's imported like this:

```
<template>
  <Footer />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import Footer from "@components/Footer/Footer.vue";
</script>
```

However, I keep this error when building (`npm run dev`):

> ERROR  Failed to load url
> /components/src/components/Footer/Footer.vue (resolved id:
> /components/src/components/Footer/Footer.vue) in
> /Users/jamie/Documents/code/project/packages/project/src/pages/Layout/BaseLayout.vue.
> Does the file exist?

Comment: Asuming that `.nuxt.config.ts` and `/components` folder are at the same level, your alias should be `"@components": "./components/src/components"` with one single dot at the begining.

Comment: @Guille that's not the case it's a mono-repo.